# Is there any solution to transfer a partitular category and there sub category from magento 2 to another magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, category, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I need to transfer a particular categories of products to another Magento 2 site with all the attributes image and all

Comment: easy way i think try to transfer database to database

Comment: but the other side is a live one which having 20000 products so it the server will crash will export.